# OpenGL blend previous N renderings without using N targets

Tags: opengl

I am blending my previous 5 renderings at each frame by having 5 render targets in the same FBO. At each frame I bind

```
base_target + frame%5
```

and in the fragment shader I go through all textures from base_target to base_target + 4 and sum them up and display the result. It works fine but I would like to blend more, like 10. The problem is that the maximum number of render targets is 8.

Is there a way to overcome this? Can I have a render target that is in fact a texture array with a large number of elements and then choose, at each iteration, in which of the textures to render to?

Comment: Have you thought about using texture arrays?

Comment: That is what I was thinking but I have only read from them, I have never used them as render targets. Can you show me any example code on how to add a texture array to a fbo and render to a specific texture inside the array (and then switching to the next one for the next frame)?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want but I can give you this pointer to [layered rendering](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Layered_Images).

Comment: so normally I would do glDrawBuffers and tell which targets to draw to and then in the shader I write layout(location = n) sampler2D something. In the case of an array of textures I would bind the fbo with only one target (i suppose the array is a single target), then how do I tell it to write to the 3rd texture?

Comment: As written [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shaders#Layered_rendering_2) you can specify (in the geometry shader) on which layer of the texture a primitive is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is only three render targets required:

- 1st RT is ACCUMULATION buffer.
- 2nd RT is CURRENT frame buffer.
- 3rd RT is TEMPORARY buffer.

Algorithm:

1. Render current frame into CURRENT RT.
2. Blend ACCUMULATION RT with CURRENT RT and put the result into TEMPORARY RT.
3. Swap ACCUMULATION RT and TEMPORARY RT.
4. Present ACCUMULATION RT.